# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kdconnector' in test script after checking things like PYTHONPATH, __init__.py etc

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

I created the following script to test for ModuleNotFound error I am getting in other scripts.

```
#kdconnecotsite/facebookapi/methods/testing.py

from kdconnector.models import Master, ClientAccounts, Client, Campaigns, Ads

def Execute(access_token, app_secret, ad_id):
    return "test completed"

# Example usage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('example usage test')
    access_token = 'EAAUIU8EilCcBABhtG7ZAQKUPMuZBo8NWOUwhBhma5MaKS2VI3s0U8W3aARwkbqKoxe0zyo4Vsdc7MStyEvyRoWvptiDICaiFTSaU5ZAlANea2nziOHuNxyNaBn9w1O3y0ZCZCk03dpd2NeBr7q6qmOixYCaHYMaEuZCn7ZCO1llBKYYHGPGtA6TVOucsPWZBLHcZD'
    ad_id = '23853970342650529'
    app_secret = '123456789'

    result = Execute(access_token, app_secret, ad_id)
    print('result = %s', result)
```

the PYTHONPATH includes the kdconnectorsite folder above the testing.py script as well as the kdconnector folder.  On creating the script, vscode finds kdconnector, models, and all the models as I type in the script.

Running the script in vscode yields, `File "c:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\kdconnectorsite\facebookapi\methods\testing.py", line 3,  in <module> from kdconnector.models import Master, ClientAccounts, Client, Campaigns, Ads ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kdconnector'`

```
Running check does not complain.

(venv) PS C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\kdconnectorsite> python manage.py check
kdconnectorsite.__init__
opened logging.yaml
2024-01-20 10:46:38,394 - kdconnectorsite - INFO - Configured the logger!
2024-01-20 10:46:38,897 - kdconnector.models - INFO - Now logging in models
2024-01-20 10:46:38,897 - kdconnector.models - INFO - Now logging in models
2024-01-20 10:46:38,919 - kdconnector.admin - INFO - Now logging in admin
2024-01-20 10:46:38,919 - kdconnector.admin - INFO - Now logging in admin
2024-01-20 10:46:39,217 - kdconnector.fbugenerator - INFO - Now logging in FBUGenerator
2024-01-20 10:46:39,217 - kdconnector.fbugenerator - INFO - Now logging in FBUGenerator
2024-01-20 10:46:39,218 - kdconnector.valuegenerator - INFO - Now logging in valuegenerator
2024-01-20 10:46:39,218 - kdconnector.valuegenerator - INFO - Now logging in valuegenerator
2024-01-20 10:46:39,219 - facebookapi.fetchMetadata - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,219 - facebookapi.fetchMetadata - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,237 - facebookapi.fetchInsights - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,237 - facebookapi.fetchInsights - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,240 - facebookapi.fetchCampaign - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,240 - facebookapi.fetchCampaign - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,242 - kdconnector.serializers.clientserializer - INFO - Now logging in ClientSerializer
2024-01-20 10:46:39,242 - kdconnector.serializers.clientserializer - INFO - Now logging in ClientSerializer
2024-01-20 10:46:39,244 - kdconnector.views - INFO - Now logging in views
2024-01-20 10:46:39,244 - kdconnector.views - INFO - Now logging in views
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

I have looked through similar posts on stack overflow and checked all the points I found that applied, and nothing works.  I even thought abouet creating anew repo and building module by module to check the structure, but it was all the same.

I even tried ChatGPT with this testing.py and checked all its suggestions.

What do I try next, or more likely, some minute detail I missed?

Mike Oliver

Here is the structure for C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\

[image: Folder Structure Showing location of testing.py]

PYTHONPATH

C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: Julkar9 done thanks and added PYTHONPATH

Comment: Accessing django components in standalone scripts is a little different. You need to start the django engine somehow. For now try running `python manage.py shell` then import `from facebookapi.methods.testing import Execute` , and run `print(Execute('','',''))`. See if this executes without any error

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you, @Julkar9 who commented,

> Accessing django components in standalone scripts is a little different. You need to start the django engine somehow. For now try running python manage.py shell then import from facebookapi.methods.testing import Execute , and run print(Execute('','','')). See if this executes without any error –
> Julkar9

That was it and solved the problem.